# Count all entry records daily of the month and return 0 if no records found in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to count the entry records every day of a month with a specific branch but the result of my query provided below is a mismatch of the records in my database. Supposed to be the total record of the DateEntry 2020-03-02 = 9 AND 2020-03-03 = 2. Any help, please!

Thank you!

**Sample Data:**

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  ID   |   BranchName   |  UploadSpeed(mbps) |  DownloadSpeed(mbps) | DateCreated |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  1    |    Cebu        |      2.12          |       3.23           |  2020-03-2  | 
|  2    |    Cebu        |      5.23          |       0.21           |  2020-03-2  | 
|  3    |    Cebu        |      3.21          |       2.34           |  2020-03-2  | 
|  4    |    Cebu        |      2.02          |       3.5            |  2020-03-2  | 
|  5    |    Cebu        |      5.06          |       4.8            |  2020-03-2  | 
|  6    |    Cebu        |      4.78          |       1.09           |  2020-03-2  | 
|  7    |    Cebu        |      3.34          |       4.13           |  2020-03-2  | 
|  8    |    Cebu        |      2.22          |       6.22           |  2020-03-2  | 
|  9    |    Cebu        |      1.45          |       1.21           |  2020-03-2  | 
|  10   |    Cebu        |      0.31          |       1.24           |  2020-03-3  | 
|  11   |    Cebu        |      2.41          |       4.13           |  2020-03-3  | 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Query:**

```
            DECLARE

                @Branch     VARCHAR(70) = 'Cebu',
                @StartDate  DATE        = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0),
                @EndDate    DATE        = DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0));

            WITH days AS
            (
              SELECT DATEADD(DAY, n, DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, @StartDate), 0)) as [Date]
                FROM ( SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) + 1)
                        n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id]) - 1
                       FROM sys.all_objects ORDER BY [object_id] ) AS n
            )
            select convert(varchar(10), days.[Date], 120) AS DailyDate,  
                CASE WHEN count(t.Id) > 0 THEN COUNT(t.Id) ELSE 0 END AS TotalEntry

                FROM days LEFT OUTER JOIN InternetMonitoring as t
                ON t.DateCreated >= days.[Date] AND t.DateCreated < DATEADD(DAY, 1, days.[Date])
                AND EXISTS(SELECT 1
                FROM Branches AS t2
                WHERE t2.Id = t.BranchId
                 t2.Branch LIKE '%'+ @Branch +'%')
            GROUP BY days.[Date],CAST(t.DateCreated AS DATE)
            ORDER BY days.[Date];
```

**Result:**

```
|-------------------------|
| DateEntry  | TotalEntry |
|-------------------------| 
|2020-03-01  |      0     |
|2020-03-02  |      7     |
|2020-03-03  |      1     |
|2020-03-04  |      0     |
|2020-03-05  |      0     |
|2020-03-06  |      0     |
|2020-03-07  |      0     |
|2020-03-08  |      0     |         
|2020-03-09  |      0     |
|2020-03-10  |      0     |
|2020-03-11  |      0     |
|2020-03-12  |      0     |
|2020-03-13  |      0     |
|2020-03-14  |      0     |
|2020-03-15  |      0     |
|2020-03-16  |      0     |
|2020-03-17  |      0     |
|2020-03-18  |      0     |
|2020-03-19  |      0     |
|2020-03-20  |      0     |
|2020-03-21  |      0     |
|2020-03-22  |      0     |
|2020-03-23  |      0     |
|2020-03-24  |      0     |
|2020-03-25  |      0     |
|2020-03-26  |      0     |
|2020-03-27  |      0     |
|2020-03-28  |      0     |
|2020-03-29  |      0     |
|2020-03-30  |      0     |
|2020-03-31  |      0     |
|-------------------------|
```

Comment: Please provide the sample data on which you are quering.

Comment: @Aniket. Done added data.

Answer (score 0):

substitute sub-query with your sum per day

```
declare @month smallint = 3


;with cte as (
   select 1 dd, cast(concat('2020',right(concat('00',@month),2),'01') as date) dt
   union all
   select 1 + dd, dateadd(day,1,dt) dt from cte
      where dateadd(day,1,dt) <= EOMONTh(dt,0)
)
select
dt, 
    ( -- pass dt and get the sum in the sub-query
      select sum(...)
      from ...
      where ... dt = <date>
      ...

    )
 from cte;
```